# using a pandas dataframe without headers to write to mysql with to_sql

Tags: python, mysql, pandas, dataframe, sqlalchemy

I have a dataframe created from an excel sheet (the source).
The excel sheet will not have a header row.

I have a table in mysql that is already created (the target). It will always be the exact same layout as the excel sheet.

`source_data = pd.read_excel(full_path, sheet_name=sheet_name, skiprows=ignore_rows, header=None)`

`db_engine = [function the returns my mysql engine]`

`source_data.to_sql(name=table_name, con=db_engine, schema=schema_name, if_exists='append', index=False)`

This fails with an error due to pandas using numbers as column names in the insert statement..

`[SQL: INSERT INTO [tablename] (`0`,` 1`) VALUES (%(0)s, %(1)s)]`

`error=(pymysql.err.OperationalError) (1054, "Unknown column '0' in 'field list'`

how can i get around this? Is there a different insert method i can use? do i really have to load up the dataframe with the proper column names from the table?

Comment: i'm hoping there is a way to get pandas to utilize an insert statement that does not include column names and assumes i have values for all columns..ie. insert into [tablename] values (%0, %1)

Comment: i would have hoped that would be one of the things that gets triggered when you use header=None when creating the dataframe.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe after importing the data into `Pandas`, you can rename the columns to something that is not a number, e.g. `"First", "Second", etc.` or `[str(i) for i in range(len(source_data))]`

This would resolve the issue of SQL being confused by the numerical labels.

Comment: judging by the insert statement that shows up in the error message, panda constructs it using those column names. so if its a name, it must match the table's column name.  Unless someone knows of a way to get panda to use a different insert statement style (assume the values perfectly match all the columns in the table).  Also, Using a number for the column name might work with some DBAPIs i suppose.. maybe pymySQL just doesn't support that. Would be good to hear of experiences

Answer (score 0):

Found no alternatives.. went with adding the column names to the data frame during the read..

So first i constructed the list of column names

`sql = ("select [column_name] from [table i get my metadata from];")`

`db_connection = [my connection for sqlalchemy]`

`result = db_connection.execute(sql)`

`column_names = []`

`for column in result:`

`column_names.append(column[0])`

And then i use that column listing in the read command:

`source_data = pd.read_excel(full_path, sheet_name=sheet_name, skiprows=ignore_rows,header=None, names=column_names)`

the to_sql statement then runs without error.

Comment: You could also do `col_names = [col["name"] for col in sqlalchemy.inspect(engine).get_columns("your_table_name")]`

Comment: thats likely useful for some.. but for me, the table has more columns than the file.. i'm just loading the columns that are in my metadata listing.